# Mount ext2 file on Mac

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, ext2, macfuse

I want to mount a virtual disk file that has been formatted with ext2. I want to do

```
sudo mount -t ext2 -o loop my-file mount-point
```

ext2fuse and macfuse from MacPorts are installed. I can't find an explanation of options for ext2fuse; I tried `ext2fuse my-file mount-point -o loop` but it sat there quietly doing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I think macfuse is no longer maintained and it does no work on 64-bit kernels.

You'll need to install fuse4x or osxfuse instead. The MacPorts project has been [fixing](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/30383) ext2fuse's dependency for fuse4x, but I am not sure if it's working yet.